# How to override global ValidationPipe in controller?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I use a global `ValidationPipe` with `{ transform: true, whitelist: true }` options. However, in a particular controller request I want to reuse the same class but with different validations, applying the validation groups technique of class-validator. Therefore it is necessary that I override the pipe's options to apply new options.

This is on NestJS 6.2.4. I have tried applying a new pipe at the `@Query(new ValidationPipe({groups: ['res']}))`, but the global pipe is still applied. I have applied the same logic with `@UsePipes()` but again the global pipe is applied.

Also, I have tried applying the `always: false` property along with the groups, to avoid validating the property at all times, but since this is the default behavior, it doesn't help much.

```
@IsNumberString({ groups: ['res'] })
resId: number;
```

Comment: I struggled with this and didn't come to a happy conclusion. I use a base class for creation with all the validators and then a sub-class of it extended as PartialType so that those properties can be optional. The only way I was able to override the validation was to do an OmitType and then re-declare the property with new validations.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, what I would recommend is to add the `ValidationPipe` at the ***method level*** within your controller, instead of at the controller level.

Something like this:

```js
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

    constructor(
        private readonly usersService: UsersService
    ) {
    }

    @Post()
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
        forbidUnknownValues: true,
        transform: true
    }))
    async create(@Body() createUserDtoReq: CreateUserRequestDto): Promise<UserResponseDto> {
        return await this.usersService.create(createUserDtoReq);
    }
}
```

Others might add other suggestions though.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I guess this feature is not supported as per the comment here ```https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2390#issuecomment-502042256```

Comment: Oh I see, not supported by now indeed

Comment: Are there any workaround for this? I ended up manually adding validation pipes per controller as mentioned on one of the comments on the github issue link provided by @SandeepKNair . :(

Comment: This did work for me. Obviously far from ideal but as far as I am aware the only alternative.